# Could Not Receive Email

Tags: php

I am trying to send email within `<a>` tag..But the destination is not receiving the email.

**Sender**

`<a href='http://localhost/Trying/search_cus.php?emailFromCus=$email'>Search Medicin</a>`

**Receiver**

`

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['emailFromCus'])){
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or 
        die(mysqli_error($con));
        mysqli_select_db($con,"Ajmal") or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $cusEmail=$con->real_escape_string($_GET['emailFromCus']);

        echo "<script>alert($cusEmail);</script>";
    }
    else{
         echo "error";
    }

?>
```

`

it is going to the else condition..WHAT to DO???

Comment: You are sending the `$_GET` variable and attempting to check its existence using `$_POST`. Try changing `if(isset($_POST['emailFromCus'])){` at line 3 to `if(isset($_GET['emailFromCus'])){`.

Comment: Since your variable is being passed through the URL, you need to reference it with `$_GET["emailFromCus"]` in your if statement.

Comment: yeah GET is working but it is receiving the variable not the value containing by the variable... `It is receiving the variable name $email rather it should receive something@gmail.com`